# Why light baking has too many big blocks

Tags: unity

I'm baking an `indirect lightmap`, but the result is terrible (as you can see on the ground). There are big white blocks, and one area on my object is missing, so you can see the inside of the object.

What could be the reason? I've tried to change some values in the inspector, to no avail. The current object is about `10 * 15` units.

[image]

Comment: How big is your floor plane?

Comment: 30*30 Units, scale it down?

Comment: With a 1024x1024 lightmap, a 30x30 object can only get about 34 pixels per unit - roughly a quarter of the 128 you seem to be aiming for. Have you considered using larger lightmaps, or shrinking the surface area you're trying to bake lighting for?

Comment: I shrink it and waiting to see the result, by the way, why part of my surface gone missing you can check my screen shot

Comment: That likely has nothing to do with lightmapping. Do you see that part of the surface if you move the camera to the other side? If so, then you probably need to correct the winding of those polygons in your 3D modelling software, to flip them to face outside instead of inside.

Comment: I can see that before lightmap baking,so it might not be a face normal issue

Comment: I still do not understand why lightmap size will impact the final result of my scene, I set the texel to 64 per unit, that should indicate every units should have 64*64 blocks, but why light map stretched out, does that mean I have to set the plane to (1024/64) *(1024/64) units to fit my lightmap?

Comment: A single material on a single mesh can only sample from one lightmap. If there aren't enough pixels in that lightmap to cover it to the density you want, then you'll get the maximum density the lightmap has room for.

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging and trying, I found that it was caused by the plane being too large (about `300 * 300` units), which means a resolution of `2048 * 2048` will be stretched out along the whole mesh.

Let's do the math. I set the texel to be 64, then `64 * 64` will be the total amount of blocks inside one unit. The size of my light map (`2048 * 2048`),  can only accommodate `2048 / 64 = 32` units long. Then the 32 units will wrap the 300 units mesh, thus resulting in a bad look.

Comment: Unity won't wrap the lightmap around your object multiple times (repeating patterns of light and shadow on its surface). Instead it will shrink your object's lightmap UVs until they fit inside the lightmap (effectively stretching the lightmap) so you get blockier results than the 64 texels per unit you were aiming for.